# How to show a floating image above the modal border in React native?

Tags: react-native

Is there any way to achieve this effect in react native?
I have an image that is supposed to pop on top of the modal margin.

[Floating Modal Image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/B2v0t.png)

Edit: I've already tried with position: 'absolute' and negative margin top or top but the image goes beneath the margin of the modal like this:

[Image under Modal](https://i.stack.imgur.com/PcAaS.png)

Comment: if you have the image you can create an animation loop using [framer motion](https://www.framer.com/motion/)

Answer (score 0):

Yes, use `position: 'absolute'` and negative `top` or `marginTop`.  The image must have a transparent background.

Comment: I already tried but the image goes under the modal

Comment: Please add what you have tried to your question

Comment: Added to the initial question

Comment: Please add the code. It's much harder to help without seeing the code. However it looks like your modal has `overflow: 'hidden'` set on it somewhere. You will have to either override this or create your own modal without this property set.

Answer (score 0):

You need to use zIndex.

here is a sample code that can help you.

https://snack.expo.dev/@asifiqubal/modal